# Store python function outcomes in different csvs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

The following function goal is to generate a CSV for each table generated by the for loop. Unfortunately, each CSV overwrites the previous one. How can I store the outcomes in multiple different CSVs?

```
cur = conn.cursor()
tables = ['users', 'chunks']

for table in tables:
    sql = """SELECT * FROM dwh.""" + table
    cur.execute(sql)

    rows = cur.fetchall()
    rows_df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
    rows_df.to_csv("dwh_users.csv")
```

Comment: You seem to know the concept of variables. What if you try using a variable instead of `"dwh_users.csv"`?

Comment: Not sure I entirely know the concept of variables! 

By the way, the function works, and I can see different queries results being stored correctly in the unique csv generated (the test is simple, just inverting the value in tables -> tables = ['users', 'chunks']).

But, that's the problem, I don't know how to generate multiple and separate CSVs, one per each value in tables = ['users', 'chunks'].

Comment: Then what do you think the line `"""SELECT * FROM dwh.""" + table`  is doing? What if you try to do `rows_df.to_csv("dwh_" + table + ".csv")` ?

Comment: Why, oh why, use pandas here?

Comment: Ready to hear any better solution @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: Use the standard library `csv`.

Comment: rows_df.to_csv(f"dwh_users_{table}.csv") This will create separate file for different tables

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```py
cur = conn.cursor()
tables = ['users', 'chunks']

for i, table in enumerate(tables):
    sql = """SELECT * FROM dwh.""" + table
    cur.execute(sql)

    rows = cur.fetchall()
    rows_df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
    rows_df.to_csv(f"dwh_users_{i}.csv")
```

This will name the file according to the index of the element in the list...